# Ensuing a function is run without actually running the function angular testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, integration-testing

I'm currently trying to write angular tests using Jasmine

One thing I want to test is to ensure that an angular material tile is running the correct function onClick of the the material tile.

To do this, I spy on the method to be called, I get the element which calls the function, trigger the event and assert on if the spy was clicked

```
spyOn(router, 'router.href="/"');
let element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.matTile1select'));
element.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(..);
```

However, when I trigger the event handler, my tests will actually cause the function to execute, thereby causing a failure

I don't want to actually test the function being called itself, just that it is actually being called, and so I'm wondering, is there a way to ensue a function is executed, without actually running the function itself?

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming by 'function' you mean a function in your component that gets called on click.  In that case, simply spyOn the relevant component function.  This will stub it (prevent it from being executed) but you can verify the method was called, and even what it was called with.

Something like this:

```
handleSpy = spyOn(component, 'clickHandler');
spyOn(router, 'router.href="/"');
let element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.matTile1select'));
element.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(handleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* correct params */);
```

If you want to post your complete `component.spec.ts` and `component.ts`, I could be more specific with the code needed.

I hope this helps.